# Sending enum via PUT method, Retrofit | Error 400

Tags: android, rest, http, retrofit, 400-bad-request

I want to send enum class to API via Retrofit. For parsing I'm using Gson.

Enum class that I'm sending:

```
enum class TaskState {
NOT_ASSIGNED,
IN_PROGRESS,
CLOSED,
DELETED }
```

My Retrofit method:

```
 @PUT("/project/76fd04cc-ae1e-4589-8fe7-11c4f16ce067/task/{taskId}/state/")
suspend fun updateState(
    @Path("taskId") taskId: String,
    @Body state: TaskState
)
```

Unfortunately, when I invoke this function, I receive an HTTP 400 error. The headers, project ID, task ID, and TaskState are all 100% correct and in accordance with the API documentation. Other methods described in the documentation work.
Below is the link do API's docs. Method that I want to use is described last.

[image]

Link to the docs: https://task-manager-api-401408.lm.r.appspot.com/docs/#/default/editTaskState

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the `enum` value as a `string`.
It doesn't know that it is a `body enum`.

Sample Usage

```
data class TaskStateBody(val state: String)
```

..

```
@Body state: TaskStateBody
```

...

```
val stateBody = TaskStateBody(TaskState.CLOSED.name)
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.